# Xamarin UITableView to create a menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin

I am using a UITableView to create a menu in Xamarin. I am looking for the best (most clean) way to bind the actions to a button click / RowSelected event. Currently, I am using the following method to check which button is clicked. However, this seems a bit dirty since I am constantly checking for the menu item names. There must be a better way do reach the same goal. Any help or hints in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

My TableViewSource:

```
public class MenuSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private List<string> categories;
    private List<string> firstMenuItems;
    private List<string> secondMenuItems;
    private List<string> thirdMenuItems;
    private UITableViewController parent;

    public MenuSource (UITableViewController parentController)
    {
        this.categories = new List<string>() {"First menu category", "Second menu category", "Third menu category" };
        this.firstMenuItems = new List<string>() {"First", "Second", "Third" };
        this.secondMenuItems = new List<string>() { "First" };
        this.thirdMenuItems = new List<string>() {"First", "Second" };
        this.parent = parentController;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
    {
        return categories.Count;
    }

    public override string TitleForHeader (UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return categories [(int)section];
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        if (categories [(int)section] == "First menu category") {
            return firstMenuItems.Count;
        } else if (categories [(int)section] == "Second menu category") {
            return secondMenuItems.Count;
        } else {
            return thirdMenuItems.Count;
        }
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("MenuCell");

        if(cell == null){
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, "MenuCell");
        }

        if (categories [(int)indexPath.Section] == "First menu category") {
            cell.TextLabel.Text = firstMenuItems [indexPath.Row];
        } else if (categories [(int)indexPath.Section] == "Second menu category") {
            cell.TextLabel.Text = secondMenuItems [indexPath.Row];
        } else {
            cell.TextLabel.Text = thirdMenuItems [indexPath.Row];
        }

        return cell;
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (categories [(int)indexPath.Section] == "First menu category") {
            if (firstMenuItems [(int)indexPath.Row] == "First") {

            } else if (firstMenuItems [(int)indexPath.Row] == "Second") {

            } else {

            }
        } else if()...

            etc.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean when you say menu? Assuming thogh that it is just a straight forward UITableView then did you consider using MvvmCross?

Then you can just do binding like so:

```
   set.Bind (MyTable).For ("SetDataSource").To ((vm) => (vm.SavedItems)).WithConversion (tableadapter,null);
```

Where

```
var tableadapter = new BackupRestoreTableCellConverter (MyTable, DataContext);
```

Have a look at Stuart Lodge's videos N=3 & N=6.5 [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W) his videos are great!

Hope this helps